# Find a subview by it's identifier

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, swift3, nsview

I made a view in Interface Builder, with some elements on it. Now I want to find a specific element in my viewcontroller to alter a property of said element. What I did, or try to do, was give the element the following identifier: `idtagtest`, and I tried to find it on the view:

`self.view.subviews["idtagtest"]`

That didn't do it, so I looked on, but I didn't see anything like a `.find` method or something like that. So, is there a way to find a subview by it's identifier?

Thanks.

Comment: Give the view a tag and then you can find it with UIView::viewWithTag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need to do is link your subview in the Storyboard to your subclass via an `@IBOutlet`. [Here is a tutorial](https://www.ralfebert.de/ios/storyboards-outlets-actions/). Alternatively you can also loop through the array of subviews, however, I wouldn't recommend this a default way of locating subviews.

Comment: This pretty much does it! thanks, Keep in mind that the tut is in german though haha

Comment: Sorry about that. Heres another one: http://www.idev101.com/learn/interface_builder_connections.html